# moving asp.net(express) app with databases(sql server express) to server 2008 R2 without errors

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, windows-server-2008

i'm trying to move an asp.net application to a server with windows server 2008 R2 installed, but when i try to get it on the server it keeps giving me errors with sql-server connection strings and other things.

i have 2 databases 1 used for loging in(using asp's build in login form)
and 1 with customer database, running on sql server 2008 express with 3 tables
everything works on the windows 7 i installed it on but i find it hard to find a good tut to do it,

preferrably moving the asp.net app and database over usb since my windows 7 isn't at the same location as the server
(ps i have sql server express and iis installed on the server

Comment: annyone?? please help me

Comment: does no one know how to do it without a sh!tload of errors??